# Avoid redirect cycle when combining access_by_lua with ngx.exec to a (named) location

Tags: nginx, lua

I want to change an existing nginx configuration in a way where I can completely "mask" the configuration and proxy everything to the upstream when a certain cookie is available (to hide a certain server).

This includes not just some `location` directives but basically every location directive (as opposed to set or map a variable and update n-location's try_files and more).

My basic idea was to use **lua** and jump into the Rewrite/Access phase like this:

```
access_by_lua_block {
  # proceed as usual if our cookie is not detected
  if ngx.var.cookie_demo ~= nil and string.len(ngx.var.cookie_demo) ~= 32 then
    return
  end
  # proxy and return w/out further processing
  ngx.exec("@ngxbackend")
  return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
}

# proxy upstream
location @ngxbackend {
  include /etc/nginx/proxy_params_demo;
  proxy_pass https://demo-upstreams;
}
```

But this leads to an ERR with **rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@ngxbackend"** as the named location is probably never reached because of the access_by_lua_block after it's internal redirect.

Can I solve this by use of variables and further condition checking?